# How to print serial number using for loop in crystal report formula field?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

i need to print only serial number 1 to 30 in crystal report with out any records in detail section. please help me.

```
    numbervar i=1; 
For i:=1 to 30 Do 
( whileprintingrecords; 
numbervar sno; 
sno:=sno+1; 
sno; 
i=i+1; );
```

Comment: didn't got your code nor didn't get your requirement

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple solution provided in crystal report.

just add special field "Record Number" and it will display sr no in detail section.

Happy Coding.

Comment: I mark this answer very useful & so easy way compare with others.

Answer (score 0):

add a report parameter field say ?display, this you can use in report to put in details section.
Go to Parameters field ->right clcik add parameter give name ?display
in formula editor write the following

```
stringvar strCount;  //holds your number 1 2 3 4 5.... 30
numbervar i=1; 
For i:=1 to 30 Do 
( whileprintingrecords; 
numbervar sno; 
sno:=sno+1; 
strCount:= strCount+ ' ' + ToText(sno);
i=i+1; );
{?display}=strCount;
```